# Backward compatibility of Hadoop Streaming

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro

AFAK, Hadoop Streaming only support text input, which means the data is organized by lines. but the mapper code will become messy if we want backward compatibility, supporting different versions of log lines in the same mapper program wrote in c++.

I used to consider avro or protobuf, but it seems that they are not supported in streaming mode, is it true?

and is there any other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other input/output formats can also be [used](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.15.2/streaming.html#Specifying+Other+Plugins+for+Jobs) along with Hadoop Streaming.

Avro [support](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/07/avro-data-interop/) had been added for Hadoop Streaming. See [AVRO-808](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-808) & [AVRO-830](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-830). Also this [Thread](http://search-hadoop.com/m/Qty1hxlXmb2) might be useful.

I could not find InputFormat and OutputFormat classes for ProtoBuf. So, they need to be custom [created](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/issues/63).

Answer (score 2):

Just for information, hadoop streaming supports binary input/output.

Look for [-io rawbytes](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/mapreduce/r0.21.0/streaming.html#Specifying+the+Communication+Format) option.

I created a prototype which was able to consume SequenceFile (I think - it was long ago).

I abandoned the idea because I had to deserialize Java Hadoop *Writables from the stream. And C# BinaryReader
uses little-endian encoding, while Java uses big-endian. So mapper became more complicated that it should be.

Anyway, it is possible.